# csv writer adds double quotes twice in python

Tags: python, html, csv

I have written a python script to append href attribute and  tag to a string holding a url which is in a csv file. The problem is that the result is not as expected. The resulted html string has got an extra double quote instead of single. Any suggestion how to fix this?
Below is the snippet:

```
InputFile = open('data1.csv', 'rb')
OutputFile = open('data3.csv', 'a+b')

CsvReader_InputFile = csv.reader(InputFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='\"')
CsvWriter_OutputFile = csv.writer(OutputFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='\"')

Row_InputFile = CsvReader_InputFile.next()
Row_InputFile[2] = "<a href=\"" + Row_InputFile[2] + "\">Link</a>"
CsvWriter_OutputFile.writerow(Row_InputFile)
```

Output:

```
"<a href=""http://www.google.com"">Link</a>"
```

Wanted Output:

```
"<a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>"
```

Comment: Where is `Row_InputFile[2]` coming from? (I'm guessing it's because you put quotes in the base line, and also told the csv writer to quote it).

Answer (score 9):

This is correct behaviour. Double quotes are escaped inside csv value.

If you want to output without escaping try [csv.QUOTE_NONE](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html)

```
csv.writer(OutputFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: Exactly. What do you expect when the quote character is inside a string? It has to be escaped somehow, and doubling them up is a common convention.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this when trying to store a JSON object as a string in a column in a csv. I had single quotes around a string filled with double quotes.
my row of data looked like

```
['foo', 'bar', '{"foo":"bar". "bar":"foo"}']
```

Doing this solved it for me

```
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar="\'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are having a `"Error: need to escape"` error:

Try this:

```
writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='|', quotechar='',escapechar='\\')
```